# Receiving local broadcast packet sent from a "supernet"

Tags: c, linux, sockets, broadcast, subnet

My question is for Linux, in C.

Say host A on subnet /16 is sending a broadcast UDP packet. (ie. by broadcasting to xxx.xxx.255.255)

Is there a way for host B on the sub-subnet with a subnet mask /24 to receive that broadcast?

My test program on host B waits on the right port but does not receive anything if A sends to xxx.xxx.255.255. But it does when xxx.xxx.xxx.255 is used.

Moreover I have constraints that
1. I cannot change network config,
2. Legacy program running on Host A doing that cannot be changed either.

Thanks!

Comment: To be exact, you receive the ethernet frame sent to x.x.255.255, but you dont get the ip datagram

Comment: I guess that's why tcpdump captures it? Thanks! I am just gonna dig into that level...

Comment: Ethernet has a source and destination address field.  There are some reserved addresses on ethernet, and one of the reserved addresses is a 'broadcast'... specifically, that's all 48 bits in the destination ethernet (i.e. Mac) address set to 1.  If a NIC sees a broadcast, it will send the packet up the host's stack.  When your IP layer sees this frame, it looks to see whether it is addressed correctly at the IP layer... that is why you can't receive it via UDP... mismatched subnets get rejected by the IP layer.

Answer (score 1):

No, and it sounds like your network is configured incorrectly.

You cannot have overlapping networks.  Either you have a /16 network, and *every* host within that /16 uses `255.255.0.0` as the netmask; or you have broken it up into smaller networks, in which case each smaller network will have its own netmask and broadcast address.

Comment: They are on the same network but I guess the legacy program that is broadcasting (which I cannot change) is sending with broadcast address on /16. Thx anyway!

Comment: @kennyc: Possibly the program was written a long time ago, when classful addressing was still in use.  These days, you cannot infer the broadcast address from the network address alone, you also require the netmask.

Answer (score 0):

try broadcasting to the subnet that computer is on. x.x.?.255

e.g.

```
ip is 24.234.123.?
broadcast to 24.234.123.255
```

since the computer is locked to the subnet /24 it will be locked only to ip's in its range.

and its broadcast is within its range.

Comment: Thanks! Im sorry that I forgot to mention I cannot change the program that is currently broadcasting, nor can I change the network config.

Comment: sounds like you need another server on the network that can rebroadcast.

Comment: or you could put the network card in promiscuous mode, but if you cant change the netmask, then you likely cant put the card in promiscuous mode.